# A Sturm-Liouville Problem with continuous spectrum and infinite point spectrum?

Tags: fourier-analysis, spectral-theory, sturm-liouville

Does someone have an example of a Sturm-Liouville problem on $\mathbb{R}$ with real coefficients that has an infinite point spectrum in $(-\infty,0]$ and continuous spectrum equal to $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Please excuse me for posting an unrelated question here: May I ask why you deleted https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3865642/42969? That looked like an interesting question to me and I *think* that it can be solved with complex analysis tools.

Comment: Yes, that one...